# Oscillator circuit with TL071 opAmp for amateur very short range AM radio

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, amplitude-modulation

I stumbled upon [this nice video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3I_e7gIyfQg) and thought I'd try to reproduce the experiment. Basically the video shows how to build an AM transmitter circuit using an opamp, some resistors and a capacitor. This is the circuit schematics for the oscillator that should generate the carrier wave:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5HmNc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The carrier wave should be at the OUT node right? My problem is that I do not understand how can this circuit oscillate since it is getting constant voltages as input and the video does not say anything about any function generator. My guess is that instead of 9 Volts in the voltage divider I should use a function generator with the carrier wave (possibly a 9V sine wave). Am I right or did I miss some component/key concept? Also by simulating the circuit with the potentiometer set to 0 on LTspice I get no oscillation at the OUT node but just a constant voltage (as expected) of 3.6V.

EDIT: the circuit should work in the 300kHz - 1.2MHz range

Comment: Please include the potentiometer, it shouldn't be difficult to add in circuitlab. It may be important to understand the "spirit" of the circuit. No one's going to sit through a video to answer a question.

Comment: @pipe potentiometer added.

Comment: Hm, but what's the potentiometer wiper connected to?

Comment: @pipe It's a manual potentiometer such as this https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b5/Potentiometer.jpg

Comment: @pipe if you do not rotate it it's basically like having a bigger R3 resistor. If you can rotate it at 300kHz or 1.2MHz in order to make the circuit oscillate I'd be very surprised though :) that is why I took it out from the simulation.

Comment: Your diagram is still wrong. The wiper should be connected to R3, and the other end of the pot should be unconnected.  That makes a very large difference to things.

Comment: @JRE Could you please submit a full answer? That might be where I am getting this wrong... Thanks.

Comment: When designing with potentiometer it is sometimes better to consider the high case (10kΩ) and the low case (1Ω) when analyzing your circuit

Comment: @laptop2d thanks for the advice, I was trying to simulate the low case with a 0.01 \Omega value but failed, then I found out in order to make the circuit oscillate I had to set the transient simulation to start the voltage from 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the video shows how to build an AM transmitter circuit using an opamp,
>   some resistors and a capacitor.

It's a relaxation oscillator and here's a simplified version using a schmitt trigger: -

[image]

However, as a carrier wave it's poor because it's basically a square wave and not a sinewave. If you are going to transmit (illegally or not) don't use a square wave as an oscillator because you'll broadcast your transmission at the fundamental frequency of the carrier (say) 1 MHz and every odd harmonic up into hundreds of MHz i.e. you become a polluter.

Anyway, back to your question, When the inverter output changes state from zero to one, it charges the capacitor up (via the resistor) until the cap voltage triggers the upper limit in the schmitt trigger. This forces the output to zero and the capacitor discharges via the resistor. Back to square one and the process repeats.

If you can follow the above circuit operation then you should be able to figure out that your circuit is identical in nature.

Hint: inside my circuit hides R1, R2 and R4 and, because they are hidden internally, there is no need to show the non-inverting input.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'll work on it and try to figure it out. Thanks for the hint on the square vs sine wave. As for the legal side, the idea is simply to replicate the experiment in the video and recreate that very limited range (1, 2 m) transmitter so that should be within the legal boundaries I think.