# Failed to get desired output of a pulse width modulation circuit simulation

Tags: analog, pwm, simulation, modulation, multisim

I was given an assignment to simulate this circuit by first adjusting the variable resistor to get V=0 at the non inverting end of the opamp then observe the waveform at the output.

I am getting an AC wave at the non-inverting opamp and when I change the variable resistor value it reaches +12 at R=100% and -12 at R=0. Anything between makes an AC wave.

How do I get V=0?

I attached a picture of the circuit below and the AC wave:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is `V1` connected while you are adjusting `R3` ?  Please change the waveform image to clearly show the X scale and Y scale. Are you doing this in an *actual* circuit ? Or just in the simulator ?

Comment: @AJN only on simulator

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore V1 then you have a classic op-amp/comparator relaxation oscillator circuit that you also find in this SE question:

[Oscillator circuit with TL071 opAmp for amateur very short range AM radio](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/251171/oscillator-circuit-with-tl071-opamp-for-amateur-very-short-range-am-radio)

and these other web pages:

- https://publicism.info/science/electronics/11.html
- https://circuitdigest.com/tutorial/relaxation-oscillator-using-op-amp

The output will be a square wave with a period of about 75 uS between +12 and -12 (the op-amp supply rails)

When you add V1 you should get a frequency modulated square wave that looks like this:

[image]

Note how the time between the pulses increases and decreases every 2 milliseconds which corresponds to the 500 Hz frequency of V1.

I would first remove V1 and make sure you can get a square wave output from the classic relaxation oscillator circuit. I've had good results setting the pot to 25% or 75%.

You can also try using an ideal op-amp model instead of a 741.

After you get the relaxation oscillator working, then add V1.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the the schematic of an op amp square wave oscillator. Does it look familiar?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbU60l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That's right, it's *your* circuit - less the input signal and capacitor.

But how is it an oscillator? R1 is connected from the output to the non-inverting input, providing positive feedback. If the output voltage goes up or down by even a tiny amount the feedback through R1 will cause it to rapidly go further in that direction, until it gets (close to) the supply rail. R2 then charges C2 up or down until the voltage on the inverting input goes past the voltage on the non-inverting input input, causing the output to switch to the opposite rail. This cycle repeats continuously producing a square wave at the output.

To stop the oscillation you can temporarily disconnect R1 and C2, then adjust the potentiometer (represented here by R3 and R4) to 50% to make the non-inverting input 0 V. You should also disconnect the input signal from C1 to stop it from interfering with the DC voltage at the non-inverting input.

After doing this the op amp's output should be close to 0 V. Now add the other components back in (first R1 and C2, then the input signal) and observe the waveforms that occur.